# Select numeric value as hex 16 in SQL

Tags: sql, select, binary, hex

i have a value in my table where i want to select and convert the value to hex in a SQL query directly in select statements.

Value: 59476
Expected value 3539343736 ( need to achieve same result as for example using online "text to hex converter" https://www.online-toolz.com/tools/text-hex-convertor.php)

Example:
`select convert(varchar(16), dbo.comminfo_hlaseni_ct.lid,2)  as  HEXA_conv`

this leads to a value '59476' where  the binary data in this query field are 00000000: 35 39 34 37 36  and i need somehow to extract the 3539343736 as a string .
i tried to google, found lot of solutions but non of them worked properly in my case.

any suggestions?

Comment: What's the database?

Comment: Your questions is unclear. It seems that you want as ASCII to hexa converter. What happens with Unicode characters, or characters between 128-255? I'm voting to close since it's unclear.

Comment: I have  MSSQL database

Comment: ok, let me say i will have only numbers in the field i want to convert

Comment: If you only have digits, then you can prepend each one with a `3`, and you'll be done. That's how ASCII was designed.